# Convert Char Input to Decimal Output - dont understand

Tags: c

so i am learning c today. I wrote some code to get input with getchar() and save it in a variable to understand how the input to integer works.

So if give a input with my keyboard like "1" and press enter i get a Value of 4910 back. I expected the value of 49 cause the decimal Ascsii code for the Char "1" is 49. Where does the 10 come from?

```
#include <stdio.h>
/* count lines in input */
main()
{
    int c;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
        printf("%d",c);

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

10 is the ASCII code of the newline character, `'\n'`. You input this character when you hit Enter.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense.. Sorry for the Question